# Fallout 3 does not work after messing with mods

Tags: fallout-3

Hello I have Fallout 3 and it was working great but I decided to install mods using Nexus mod manager. Every time I started the game it crashed. So now I disabled all the mods and even deleted them and when I go into Fallout 3 and click new game the game says: "Fallout 3 has stopped working". What do I do?

I have deleted Steam local content 3 times now and there is nothing in my data folder related to mods.

Here's an image of what my Fallout 3 folder looks like:

[image: My Folder]

Can someone please help me out and tell me how to fix my game and put it back to the way it was?

Comment: Have you tried verifing the local cache?

Comment: what do u mean @Frank

Comment: You got it on Steam, right?  In Steam, right click the game, go Properties, Local Files, and click the Verify Integrity of Game Cache.  See what that does.

Comment: @Frank it still crashes

Comment: I don't recall Fallout 3 being all that happy with Windows 10. In fact, the Steam page even says it's not fully compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: yes but it worked up until yesterday

Comment: Maybe try removing all files/uninstalling, and redownloading it? You may think you have removed all mods, but sometimes remnants can be left over, corrupting saves and the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Back it up somewhere and then delete `C:\users\[YOU]\appdata\local\[Bethesda game name]`